# Error when installing CouchDB on OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, installation, homebrew, couchdb

I'm trying to install CouchDB on Mountain Lion. 
I've followed the guide at http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_OSX
I get to the point where I have to do `brew install couchdb`, but when I do that I get:

```
    Erlang <= R15B03-1 is required to install.

    You have a erlang version R15B03-1

    The work-around is:

     brew unlink erlang
     cd /usr/local
     git checkout 168742f Library/Formula/erlang.rb
     brew install erlang
     brew install couchdb

     Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

Notice that I've got the version of Erlang that it asks for, but it fails anyway.

When I first tried to install CouchDB I had MacPorts installed, but I uninstalled that and tried again with no luck.

running `brew doctor` gives me:

```
Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libaspell.15.1.4.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libcdt.5.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libcgraph.6.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgimpprint.1.1.3.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgraph.5.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgs.8.64.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgvc.6.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgvpr.2.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libpathplan.4.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libpspell.15.1.4.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libusb-0.1.4.4.4.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libusb-0.1.4.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libusb.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libusbpp-0.1.4.4.4.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libusbpp-0.1.4.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libusbpp.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libxdot.4.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/ZeppelinUpdater.dylib
Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
    /usr/local/lib/libaspell.la
    /usr/local/lib/libgimpprint.la
    /usr/local/lib/libpspell.la
    /usr/local/lib/libusb.la
    /usr/local/lib/libusbpp.la
Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/fuse.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libcdt.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libcgraph.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libgraph.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libgvc.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libgvpr.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libpathplan.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libxdot.pc
Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
    /usr/local/lib/libgimpprint.a
    /usr/local/lib/libusb.a
    /usr/local/lib/libusbpp.a
Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:

    2to3
    2to3-2.7
    idle
    idle2.7
    pydoc
    pydoc2.7
    python
    python-config
    python2.7
    python2.7-config
    pythonw
    pythonw2.7
    smtpd.py
    smtpd2.7.py

Consider amending your PATH so that /usr/local/bin
occurs before /usr/bin in your PATH.
```

Even though I changed etc/paths so that /usr/local/bin is the very first line:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

also, I'm not comfortable changing the location of the mentioned files since I have no clue what they are.

lastly I've also tried the CouchDB app from http://www.apache.org/dist/couchdb/notes/1.2.1/apache-couchdb-1.2.1.html, but when I run it I get `CouchDB Server doesn't seem to be operating properly. Check Console logs for more details.`

I don't know how to access the Console Logs...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got the same thing.  I followed the [instructions on the couchdb site](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_OSX#If_you.27ve_brewed_CouchDB_before) and ran into another issue which I [documented on stack overflow with a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490177/error-installing-couchdb-with-homebrew-osx-10-8-skip-dependency/15507222#15507222)  but I think I have a more direct solution for you.

try this, open the formula in your favorite text editor

```
vim /usr/local/Library/Formula/couchdb.rb
```

Correct the line that refers to the dependency.  If you are having problems, you can follow my solution I described on stack overflow, but you should be able to bust this out.

Hope that helps!!

-Dan

Comment: Hi @Dan. Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it does not work. The dependacy in my couchdb.rb is already `depends_on 'erlang'`. I tried to change in to `'erlang-15'` (the opposit of what worked for you) but no luck.

Comment: Hi again. I tried again and for some reason it worked this time. I got a couchDB running on my machine. YAY! 
`{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"1.2.1"}`
Time to relaxe ;)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't solve the brew problem you encountered, but you could also just download a ready to go binary distribution from the CouchDB website: http://couchdb.apache.org/#download

Comment: I think that's what I refered to when I wrote that I tried the CouchDB app. That still doesn't work...
But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Works great for me. You can view the console logs by using the Console application included in OS X. If you want to file a bug report go here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CouchDB